# How to use async function based views in DRF?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, django-rest-framework

Since Django now supports async views, I'm trying to change my code base which contains a lot of function based views to be async but for some reason its not working.

```
@api_view(["GET"])
async def test_async_view(request):
    ...
    data = await get_data()
    return Response(data)
```

When I send a request to this endpoint, I get an error saying:

> AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or
> `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a
> `<class 'coroutine'>`

Does DRF not support async views yet? Is there an alternative I can do to get this working?

Answer (score 11):

As of now, DRF doesn't support async *"api views"*. Here is an open [issue (#7260)](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/7260) in the DRF community and it is still in the discussion stage.

But, Django providing a decorator/wrapper which allow us to convert our sync views/function to async using [**`sync_to_async(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/async/#sync-to-async) wrapper.

Example,

```
@sync_to_async
@api_view(["GET"])
def sample_view(request):
    data = get_data()
    return Response(data)
```

Note that, here, `sample_view(...)` and `get_data(...)` are sync functions.

Comment: How would that help? If get_data is sync?

Comment: as I mentioned, DRF doesn't support "*async API views**. The least workaround is to use the `sync_to_async(...)`. That means the `sample_view(...)` must be a ***sync*** function and thus `get_data(...)` should also be a sync function.

Comment: I am also confused by this. If `get_data()` is the bulk of the work and must be sync, then what can `@sync_to_async` possibly achieve?

Comment: You can call it with thread safety turned off, and it will run it in a separate thread. Otherwise it will simply wrap the sync code in a wrapper context that allows the async generator to consume it, however there will be a performance loss as it will run in the same thread as the async loop and effectively block other async contexts from executing.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with `adrf`:

```
pip install adrf
```

then add it to INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'adrf',
]
```

---

```
import asyncio
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

@sync_to_async  
def do_a_network_call(some_input):  
    expensive_result = do_expensive_network_call(some_input)
    return expensive_result
    
# Class Based Views:
from adrf.views import APIView

class AsyncView(APIView):
    async def get(self, request):
        result = await asyncio.gather(do_a_network_call("some_input"))  
        return Response({"result": result})


# Function Based Views:
from adrf.decorators import api_view

@api_view(['GET'])
async def async_view(request):
    result = await asyncio.gather(do_a_network_call("some_input"))
    return Response({"result": result})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can Use this decorator in DRF

```
import asyncio
from functools import wraps


def to_async(blocking):
    @wraps(blocking)
    def run_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return asyncio.run(blocking(*args, **kwargs))

    return run_wrapper
```

Example of usage

```
@to_async
@api_view(["GET"])
async def sample_view(request):
    ...
```

Comment: Do not use `asyncio.run` with Django, as it does allow `asgiref.sync.sync_to_async` functions to work as intended(which need to be wrapped around Database calls)

Please use `asgiref.sync.async_to_sync` instead