# Async Django Rest Framework Examples

Tags: django, asynchronous, django-rest-framework

Does anyone have any examples on how I can make my DRF class based modelviews async?  Reading the Django docs it says...

> Any view can be declared async by making the callable part of it return a coroutine - commonly, this is done using async def. For a function-based view, this means declaring the whole view using async def. For a class-based view, this means making its **call**() method an async def (not its **init**() or as_view()).

I have class based views, so what I was hoping was there were examples on the correct syntax to implement the async on the **call**() method so that I can try and make my view async to make use of Django's async support.  Now, there are examples of implementing an async view if it's a function based view, meaning making the as_view() for example async [How to use async function based views in DRF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65873039/how-to-use-async-function-based-views-in-drf?rq=1)

Unfortunately, I haven't found any examples as of yet for implementing this for class based views.

Given this, I was also hoping there are examples of how I can unit test my new async class based views. I've been using APITestCase and unittest.mock to run and patch various tests on my sync views, but this doesn't support testing a coroutine, so the tests fail.

Comment: I think that no body know what you exactly mean. You need to define problem, use case or any other example / goal what you want to achieve. Maybe you mean `websockets` i dont know...

Comment: Ok thanks mon io, let me update my initial question.