# How to implement async view through class-based view(CBV) in Django

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, django-class-based-views, asgi

An AssertionError occurred while trying to operate asynchronous view as class-based view in django(CBV)

The python code i wrote is as follows.

**urls.py**

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.urls import re_path
from rest_framework import routers
from blog import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'test', views.TestView, 'hello')

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'', include(router.urls)),
    re_path(r'async_view/', include(router.urls))
]
```

**views.py**

```py
class TestView(viewsets.ViewSet):
    LOG = logging.getLogger('test')
    async def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.LOG.info("async method start!!")
        queryset = Post.objects.none
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        return HttpResponse("Hello async world!")
```

**asgi.py**

```py
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')

application = get_asgi_application()
```

When i execute command below

```
uvicorn mysite.asgi:application --limit-concurrency 12 --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80
```

then, An AssertionError occurred

```
AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'coroutine'>`
```

Which part is wrong??

Answer (score 0):

It seems Django Rest Framework does not support async views as of now.

[How to use async function based views in DRF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65873039/how-to-use-async-function-based-views-in-drf)